# ¿Cuándo se le pone tilde a más?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones, ortografía

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between “mas” and “más”](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/1855/difference-between-mas-and-mas)

The question is quite simple.

When does **mas** have an accent? Mas can mean more but it has other meanings as well.

Can someone explain to me not only the meanings but how to properly use it with accent and without it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well it actually is about the meaning. "Más" and "mas" are different words.

[Más](http://rae.es/drae/?type=3&val=m%C3%A1s&val_aux=&origen=REDRAE) can be comparative adverb or a noun.

As a comparative adverb:

> Ve más rápido.
>
> Es el más fuerte.
>
> Fuimos más de diez personas.
>
> ¡Qué casa más bonita!

As a noun, is mathematical addition "+":

> Dos más dos igual a cuatro.

[Mas](http://rae.es/drae/?type=3&val=mas) is an adversative conjunction. This means it is a linking word used to introduce a contrast statement:

> Hace frío, *mas* ayer hacía más. (Hace frío, *pero* ayer hacía más).

As you see, the first "mas" works as a linker introducing the contrast sentences, whereas the second "más" is the comparative, as it is comparing how colder was than today.

As a rule of thumb, write "mas" without tilde when you can substitute it by "pero" or "sino". The rest of cases will be "más".

Edit: As Carrigus Carraig comments, "más" is more frequent, you would never use "mas" unless you want to write something poetic, even in formal writing.

Comment: I feel like it's worth mentioning that "más" is far more frequent - as much as 15 times more frequent - than "mas", as you can see here: http://is.gd/TBC4zM . Also, (WAG alert) confusion about "mas" (a word I was never taught in my studies) may be due to writers skipping the tilde in informal contexts such as text messages, Internet comments, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The word MAS is used in two context:

1. Adverb. When you're trying to **count**, taking into account the amount.
2. Conjunction. When you're using for **contradict**. You can say a synonym for 'but', 'however'.

E.G.:

1: Dame **una** cerveza más.

2: Yo quisiera, mas **no** puedo.

Comment: There is a lot wrong with this answer.  First, there is the word *mas* and there is the word *más*.  Their spellings are similar, but not identical.  Second, you can use *más* with uncountables.  Third, *mas* is used to **contrast**, not to contradict.

Comment: @MichaelWolf Your advices: The First one is not useful, it is already mentioned. The Second one is *also* not useful, I can't (anyone) put **all** the possibilities. The Third one, you're right but, do you know what means my example?